# Resolved that the console display cannot be captured use

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined
Can't use it? I've been doing this for a long time. Has anyone encountered this problem before? You can't even use CreateApp. What's going on

#### 这是router文件夹里的index.js

```
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import VueRouter from "vue-router"
    
    Vue.use(VueRouter)
    
    const routes = []
    
    export default new VueRouter({
      routes,
      mode: "history"
    })
```

#### main.js

```
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import App from './App.vue'
    import router from "@/router";
    
    Vue.config.productionTip = false;
    
    new Vue({
      render: h => h(App),
      router
    }).$mount('#app')
```

#### 控制台的错误

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined
    at eval (index.js?a18c:4)
    at Module../src/router/index.js (app.js:1482)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (main.js:12)
    at Module../src/main.js (app.js:1470)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at Object.1 (app.js:1495)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
```

、、、、、、、、、、、、、、、、、、、
、、、、、、、、、、、、、、、、、、
、、、、、、、、、、、、、、、、、、

Comment: I have no idea if it matters, but try moving 'router' above 'render' in 'new Vue()'.  That is the way that I have always seen and written it.